# Ralink RT2790 (or maybe a RT2860), detected as two different chipsets, can't connect

Tags: wireless, 12.04, ralink

Today,
I have installed 12.04 & my wifi stopped working. Wireless gets detected as RT2790 & show available network but doesn't not connect to any wireless network(tried secured & unsecured) for some strange reason.

here are my debug logs:

```
$ lspci -vv
01:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT2790 Wireless 802.11n 1T/2R PCIe
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 130f
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 4 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at fd9f0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci

$ dmesg

[   10.376745] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   10.377050] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   10.382818] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link down
[   10.382999] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   10.383320] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   10.399893] type=1400 audit(1335469914.161:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" pid=770 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.466654] type=1400 audit(1335469914.229:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=777 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.467258] type=1400 audit(1335469914.229:12): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*" pid=777 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.471790] type=1400 audit(1335469914.233:13): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=778 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.472486] type=1400 audit(1335469914.237:14): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=778 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.813041] init: alsa-restore main process (814) terminated with status 99
[   36.626240] audit_printk_skb: 27 callbacks suppressed
[   36.626245] type=1400 audit(1335469940.389:24): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/usr/share/gvfs/remote-volume-monitors/" pid=1594 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[   68.040170] wlan0: authenticate with 00:14:78:19:8f:da (try 1)
[   68.041544] wlan0: authenticated
[   68.056069] wlan0: associate with 00:14:78:19:8f:da (try 1)
[   68.057737] wlan0: deauthenticated from 00:14:78:19:8f:da (Reason: 6)
[  197.784490] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  207.812147] wlan0: authenticate with 00:14:78:19:8f:da (try 1)
[  207.813561] wlan0: authenticated
[  207.828142] wlan0: associate with 00:14:78:19:8f:da (try 1)
[  207.829666] wlan0: deauthenticated from 00:14:78:19:8f:da (Reason: 6)
[  271.148245] wlan0: authenticate with 00:14:78:19:8f:da (try 1)
[  271.149599] wlan0: authenticated
[  271.149779] wlan0: failed to insert Dummy STA entry for the AP (error -17)
[  334.140512] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:14:78:19:8f:da by local choice (reason=2)
[  334.148263] wlan0: authenticate with 00:14:78:19:8f:da (try 1)
[  334.149624] wlan0: authenticated
[  334.149843] wlan0: failed to insert Dummy STA entry for the AP (error -17)
[  397.136541] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:14:78:19:8f:da by local choice (reason=2)
[  399.272147] wlan0: authenticate with 00:14:78:19:8f:da (try 1)
[  399.472028] wlan0: authenticate with 00:14:78:19:8f:da (try 2)
[  399.473423] wlan0: authenticated
[  399.473654] wlan0: failed to insert Dummy STA entry for the AP (error -17)

$ iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Now, I am also running Ubuntu 10.10 on this same machine, in that my wireless gets detected as RaLink RT2860 chipset & works perfectly). I can connect to internet. here is the lspci output from Ubuntu 10.10

```
01:00.0 Network controller: RaLink RT2860
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 130f
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 4 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at fd9f0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2860sta, rt2800pci
```

Interesting thing to notice here is: 
the **same card gets detected as two different chipsets(*RT2790* vs *RT2860*)**

the Wireless card in question here is:
[Asus PCE-N10 Wireless PCI Express Adapter](http://www.asus.com/Networks/Wireless_Adapters/PCEN10/). And I think chipset in this card is RT2860(not RT2790), correct me if I am wrong. I further suspect this wrong detection in Ubuntu 12.04 is the reason that it doesn't connect/work.

So,
Please let me know if my suspicion is correct? If yes, then what I need to do to fix this mess & get my wireless card working in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a bug in the Linux kernel 3.2, which was fixed in later version. I know this because I tried the latest Kernel Linux 3.4 in which this card works out of the box. I have filled out a bug report on launchpad, but so far the bug has not been fixed.

Launchpad Bug Link: [[Bug 989473] Ralink RT2860[1814:0781] Wireless card worked in 10.10, stopped working in 12.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/989473)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the fault is not in Ubuntu 12.04 itself, but **instead on the kernel**, where (amongst others) wifi drivers are included. Upgrading to an even newer kernel (or an older one=¡?) could make things work.

Another solution could be to use [ndiswrapper](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Main_Page) with the [RT2860 Windows drivers](http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/license.php?sn=5013). I know it's not ideal, but could work.